# Can we use Liferay jars in standalone services not inside liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

We have build our portlet using liferay 5.2 and in our portlet we use TagService in our services.
We are now planning to move to SOA, and would be moving services out of liferay and deploy them as RESTful services in a seperate server, only UI controllers would remain in the liferay portlet which would consume the REST services.

The problem we have is that we use tag service for inside our services in search and hence we cant move it out.

One solution is to rewrite the Tag Services which will query the liferay DB and fetch the data for our services.Other solution could be to include the liferay-impl jars for TagService.
I am not sure if this is doable and how much complicated this would get?
Has anyone done something similar before?
Or Am I missing something?
Any thoughts?

Comment: the `liferay-impl` jars themselves have so many dependencies on other jars for spring, hibernate, struts etc. So you would have to copy the whole set of jars inside WEB-INF/lib and then too I don't think it is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use Liferay webservices and build your TagServices? The following links may be of some help 
[Accessing Liferay web services](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Web+services+-+Manage+Users,+Organizations,+User+Groups,+and+Roles+via+SOAP)

and

[Consuming Lifeary Web Services](http://www.liferay.com/web/antonio.junior/blog/-/blogs/12168124)